# How to code a Closest Match String search in a database query in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, string, search

My specific problem is related to an Android project but this is not a specific android question.

I am basically just trying to come up with a way I can query a database and return results not based on exact matches but based on similar terms even outside the scope of a search on whether a String "contains" the typed value.

So for example, lets say I have a entry called "Popeye's Catfish". And lets say somebody enters the term "P's CatSalmon" and are looking for that entry. I would like to return a query list that shows essentially a "most similar" match.

I admit I am a complete novice at database queries so there might be ready answers out there that I just can't find (I did look). There are a few ways I can think to do this:

1. I could break apart the search string and look for separate parts of each string in a "contains" search of the actual entry. For example I could break out "P" "Cat" and "Salmon" search all three and do some other code to find out what the best result is. However, I'm really not sure how I would code it so that the program could pick the best segments. How would it know to pick out "cat" for example without just iterating through every possibility (which is almost certainly not realistic)?
2. I could just let the users suffer for a while until tags exist. What I mean is, once the correct entry is found by the "proper" name, I could just let users tag it with associated names and then include that separate associated name in the search by later users.

I can't come up with anything better than that based on my current level of knowledge.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I am a novice myself but perhaps if you compared by sequential character matches. Using say a hashMap you could apply a score to character which matches sequentially each term. So for example "P's CatSalmon" compared against "Popeye's Catfish" would have a score of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is some sort of find location app.  So let's assume that the number of locations is small, say less than 200.

You would start by building a search that looks for the "words" that the user typed in the locations.  In your example, we have "P's" and "CatSalmon".  "CatSalmon won't match anything, and neither will "P's".

So you return something that looks like this:

```
Locations found for "P's CatSalmon"
-----------------------------------
No locations found.  Try using different search terms.
```

So, our user types "P CatSalmon".

So you return all the locations that start with the letter P, then the locations that contain the letter P.

Something like this:

```
Locations found for "P CatSalmon"
---------------------------------
Popeye's Catfish
Public library
Hope Restaurant
...
```

Now, here's where it gets interesting.

When the user picks a location, you log the search term and the location selected.

In your example, the user would pick "Popeye's Catfish".

So later, you manually add this key value to a synonym map.

```
Key        Value
---------  ----------
CatSalmon  Catfish
```

Over time, your searches will get better because your users will define the synonyms.

So, to recap.

- You search for locations that start with a word.
- You search for locations that contain a word.
- You look in the synonym map for synonyms, and you repeat the start / contain process with the synonym(s).
- Start locations are displayed first, then contain locations.

Finally, you do all this work on the server with the database.  You pass the sorted location list to the phone.  Don't make the phone do all the work.

Comment: Yeah that's about what I figured, basically the "tags" approach. And I like the idea that I just log them automatically rather than asking for the users to do it. Glad I was at least not off base. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I put together essentially highlighting the closest matched term with a query based on the number of sequential characters

public class SequenceMatches {

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String query = "P's SalmonCat ";

    map = addTermsToHashMap(map);// add terms to a hash map
    map = compareFirstCharacter(map, query);// compare the initial first character
    map= compareSequentialCharacters(map, query);// compare terms to query and add score based on the number of matches
    printResults(map);
}


    public static HashMap<String,Integer> addTermsToHashMap(HashMap<String,Integer> map){
    String term = "Popeye's CatFish";
    String otherTerm = "Popets CatSalmon";
    map.put(term,0);
    map.put(otherTerm,0);

    return map;
    } 

    public static HashMap<String,Integer> compareFirstCharacter(HashMap<String,Integer> map,String query){

        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: map.entrySet())
        {
            String term = e.getKey();
            char [] termChar = term.toCharArray();
            char [] queryChar = query.toCharArray();

            if((queryChar[0]) == (termChar[0]))
            {
                int value = map.get(term);
                map.put(term,++value);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public static HashMap<String,Integer> compareSequentialCharacters(HashMap<String,Integer> map,String query){
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: map.entrySet())
        {
            String term = e.getKey();
            char [] termChar = term.toCharArray();
            char [] queryChar = query.toCharArray();



            for(int i = 0; i < queryChar.length -1; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < termChar.length -1; j++)
                {
                    if(queryChar[i] == termChar[j] )
                    {
                        if((queryChar[i + 1]) == (termChar[j + 1]))
                        {
                            System.out.println((queryChar[i + 1]) + " " + (termChar[j + 1]));
                            int value = map.get(term);
                            map.put(term,++value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            }   
        return map;
    }

    public static void printResults(HashMap<String,Integer> map)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is a good example Calgar, thanks for providing it. I think this combined with some dynamic adds of "tags" to the data will probably work nicely.